# Display full ISO time in OSF1

Tags: ls, tru64

I am working on an HP OSF1 (Tru64) based server and need to display file listings with the full-iso time format style.

Example of this in Ubuntu Linux,

```
user@hostname:~/Desktop$ ls -lrt --full-time
total 56
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group  3500 2014-01-28 23:02:11.036072341 +0530 sample_config.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group  9123 2014-01-28 23:02:45.290084160 +0530 vxprint.inp
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group  2312 2014-01-29 08:55:22.068250913 +0530 op_metastat.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group   348 2014-01-29 08:56:11.214369737 +0530 op_drbd.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 11844 2014-01-29 08:56:55.429858843 +0530 op_prtdiag.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group  1701 2014-01-29 11:42:08.320187594 +0530 drbd.pl
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group  1256 2014-01-30 09:23:37.037858800 +0530 prtdiag.pl
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group  5089 2014-01-30 10:00:56.357497995 +0530 crs_alerts.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group  2761 2014-01-30 10:41:31.452528726 +0530 metastat.pl
user@hostname:~/Desktop$
```

Example in Solaris SunOS,

```
user@hostname> ls -lErt
total 128750
-rwxr-x---   1 user group          174 2012-09-10 16:28:59.000000000 +0530 local.profile
-rwxr-x---   1 user group          157 2012-09-10 16:28:59.000000000 +0530 local.login
-rwxr-x---   1 user group          136 2012-09-10 16:28:59.000000000 +0530 local.cshrc
drwxr-xr-x   3 user group           96 2012-10-09 22:11:57.000000000 +0530 etc
drwxr-xr-x   2 user group           96 2012-10-11 14:48:59.000000000 +0530 Documents
user@hostname>
```

How do I display the directory listing in the same manner in OSF1?

Comment: What does `+0530` mean in the result?

Comment: @jsr It's a time zone offset, possibly indicating [Indian Standard Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/ist).

Answer (score 2):

Native `ls` does not support this.  Consider installing GNU coreutils.